# Getting errors only when building .apk

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, apk

I have an android app. I can run it on my device with no problem, but when I try to build apk file, I am getting following errors.

```
Error:warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous innerclass
Error:(org.joda.time.DateTimeZone$1) that doesn't come with an
Error:associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably  produced by a
Error:compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The  recommended
Error:solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-  date compiler
Error:and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
Error:this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
Error:indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
Error:The number of method references in a .dex file cannot exceed 64K.
Learn how to resolve this issue at https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html
:app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug FAILED
Error:Execution failed for task     ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException:   com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:   java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command  '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_79.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 2
```

Here is my dependencies:

```
dependencies {
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.1'
compile 'com.google.guava:guava:11.0.1'
compile 'com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:2.2.0'
compile files('libs/acra-4.5.0.jar')
compile files('libs/google-api-client-1.10.3-beta.jar')
compile files('libs/google-api-client-android2-1.10.3-beta.jar')
compile files('libs/google-http-client-1.10.3-beta.jar')
compile files('libs/google-http-client-android2-1.10.3-beta.jar')
compile files('libs/google-oauth-client-1.10.1-beta.jar')
compile files('libs/jackson-core-asl-1.9.4.jar')
compile files('libs/jsr305-1.3.9.jar')
compile files('/Users/emredurmus/Documents/Projects/CrmMobile1/Libs/odata4j-0.7.0-clientbundle.jar')
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'}
```

What should I do ?

Thanks

Comment: did you tried clean and rebuild project? I was also getting same error earlier. I have done the same. It worked for me

Comment: Yes I did. It also works fine on my real device. The problem is when I try to create apk.

Answer (score 2):

This is your real problem:

> `Error:The number of method references in a .dex file cannot exceed 64K.`

This is your solution:

> `Learn how to resolve this issue at https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html`

Answer (score 1):

add the following lines to my proguard-rules.pro file:

```
-keepattributes InnerClasses,EnclosingMethod
-dontoptimize
```

Answer (score 1):

You are exceeding the 64k method limit.

Replace `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'}` with only those GMS services you need.

You can include only selective APIs from the google play services that you need. Get the exact names to add here - [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup)